# PHP post data not being set calling Java Rest Web Service

Tags: java, php, rest, curl

I know there are a lot of questions related to this issue, but I'm facing an specific requirement for this purpose of posting data from PHP to a Rest Web Service. The details are explained above, but in summary, when I post data to a url (REST WS) and set the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS the data is not being added to the request.

The scenario: I have a lot of Java Web Services (REST) running as modules, for example, I have a fileUploadModule which is a REST, I have a databaseModule which is another rest and finally a SearchModule, which is another REST.

I can invoke them directly my rest modules using a link like:

```
http://[MY IP]:8020/system.file.ws.module.ModuleFile/getResults/jsonp?fileName=fileName
http://[MY IP]:8021/system.search.ws.module.ModuleSearch/getResults/jsonp?xmlQuery=myXml
```

For the case of files and database, the programmer that was managing the code before me used gwt that connected to the module through a proxy; for instance:

```
http://[MY_PROXY_IP]:8013/system.file.ws.module.ModuleFile/getResults/jsonp?fileName=fileName
```

and in my proxy I can print the value of the request received, in this case I use a GET and I can print the request as:

```
GET /system.file.ws.module.ModuleFile/getResults/jsonp?fileName=idc1&folderType=campaign&callback=__gwt_jsonp__.P0.onSuccess&failureCallback=__gwt_jsonp__.P0.onFailure HTTP/1.1
```

. Now I am responsible for search that should run through PHP. I tested the url directly to the module and it works, but if I try to it by a proxy it does not seems to be working, it reach my proxy but when I print the request it is incomplete:

```
POST /system.search.ws.module.ModuleSearch/getResults HTTP/1.1
```

and I am supposed to receive something like the module file, I share my php code, all seems to be ok, but I don't know what can I be doing wrong... when I set the parameters in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS the string is not being set

```
 $url = "http://192.168.3.41:8013/system.search.ws.module.ModuleSearch/getResults"; 
try {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$rawXml = $_POST['rawXml'];
$rawXml = str_replace("%", "%25", $rawXml);
$rawXml = str_replace("&", "%26", $rawXml);
$rawXml = str_replace("=", "%3D", $rawXml);
echo $rawXml;   
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'xmlQuery='.$rawXml);
$info = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $info;
} catch (Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

please I would really appreciate your help or observations. Than you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it with curl from the command line? e.g.

`curl --data "xmlQuery={xmlquery}" http://192.168.3.41:8013/system.search.ws.module.ModuleSearch/getResults`

Comment: yes, but I don't have the command available for terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time, I saw this without an answer. I discovered the fail of this some time ago. This issue occurred because, when reaching server side, for some reason a batch file I did not noiced was adding an additional line to my content, and whenever I read the request content with my proxies, I used a "\n" delimiter, I mean, I have been reading my data using as the EOF indicator a line jump, that's why the content was never shown. I had to modify the code inside my proxy to allow reading the request until the end, not when finding a "\n" character. I mean, the content of the post was set in every case, but a batch process was corrupting that data. So thata was the issue, I just solved it by making sure that my reader always read my entire file considering even line jumps and white lines.

Regards.